# Tensorflow: Create a batch from a list of image tensors

Tags: tensorflow

I have a function `get_image(...)` that performs preprocessing on my input images. I gather all images that belong to the same batch in a list like this:

```
batch = [get_image(file_path) for file_path in batch_files]
```

Now I want to convert this list into one single tensor with the first dimension being the batch size dimension, such that I could feed it to the input placeholder of my network.

```
_ = self.sess.run([loss],feed_dict={ input_placeholder: batch })
```

Any idea how I could do that?

```
            batch_concat = tf.placeholder(shape=[None] + self.image_shape, dtype=tf.float32) 
            for i in xrange(0,self.batch_size):
                if i == 0:
                    tmp_batch = tf.expand_dims(batch[i], 0)
                    batch_concat = tmp_batch
                else:
                    tmp_batch = tf.expand_dims(batch[i], 0)                        
                    batch_concat = tf.concat(0, [batch_concat, tmp_batch])
```

When I try to concatenate all tensors, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: The value of a feed cannot be a tf.Tensor object. Acceptable feed values include Python scalars, strings, lists, or numpy ndarrays.
```

So maybe it would be enough to convert the tensor back into a numpy array before feeding it to the network?

Comment: not clear what you want to do here. Why you don't pass the python list containing the images as your input_batch? tensorflow will convert it for you

Comment: I wanted to use the preprocessing functions provided by tf. Otherwise I would have to rewrite everything in python...

Answer (score 1):

In the TF r1.1 pack has been replaced with [tf.stack](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/stack)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [tf.pack](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/array_ops/slicing_and_joining#pack) to pack a list of tensors into a batch.

```
image_list = [get_image(file_path) for file_path in batch_files]
image_batch = tf.pack(image_list)
```

You can also use tf.concat to concatenate the list along the first dimension and reshape it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is using a tensor as a value in feed_dict. Instead of feeding `batch` as the value for input_placeholder, why don't you use `batch` instead of `input_placeholder`, assuming `batch` is your batched tensor?

So, instead of:

```
input_placeholder = tf.Placeholder(tf.int32)
loss = some_function(input_placeholder)
sess.run(loss, feed_dict={input_placeholder: batch})
```

Do:

```
loss = some_function(batch)
sess.run(batch)
```